# Using MSE to split decision tree on MLR

Tags: r, machine-learning, mlr

I'm trying to split my decision tree in MLR using MSE. Here's my code

```
library(mlr)

cl = "classif.rpart"


getParamSet(cl)

learner = makeLearner(cl = cl
                      , predict.type = "prob"
                      #, predict.type = "response"
                      , par.vals = list(split="mse")
                      , fix.factors.prediction = TRUE
)
```

And it gives me the error

```
Error in setHyperPars2.Learner(learner, insert(par.vals, args)) : 
  classif.rpart: Setting parameter split without available description object!
Did you mean one of these hyperparameters instead: minsplit cp xval
You can switch off this check by using configureMlr!
```

I Know how to do this on`rpart`. But have no ideia on `MLR`

Comment: Exactly what the error message says. The parameter is called "minsplit", not "split".

Comment: I Just look up the meaning of minsplit and it isn't the parameter that I need. Here : 
the minimum number of observations that must exist in a node in order for a split to be attempted.

Comment: Ah, I see. This parameter isn't supported by mlr at the moment.

Comment: @Lars: It's not supported for tuning but indirectly it can be set (see my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `split` parameter is passed in a list under `rpart(..., parms = list(split = "mse"))`. Therefore it can be set within mlr like this:

```
library(mlr)
cl = "classif.rpart"
learner = makeLearner(cl = cl, predict.type = "prob", par.vals = list(parms = list(split="mse")), fix.factors.prediction = TRUE)
m = train(learner, iris.task)
```

In the result we can see that it was passed correctly

```
m$learner.model$call
# rpart::rpart(formula = f, data = d, parms = list(split = "mse"), xval = 0L)
```